# Using Embarcadero 10.1 Berlin with OpenSSL (C++)

Tags: openssl, linker-errors, c++builder

I'm in the midst of trying to get OpenSSL and Embarcadero 10.1 Berlin to play nice.

I have a C++ project (VCL Form) that imports OpenSSL libraries, and then makes use of their functions (ex: openssl/evp.h).

I am still fairly new to the Embarcadero IDE, along with C++, as well as OpenSSL. Not a great combo, but this set-up is what I am required to use.

When I first started going down this OpenSSL rabbit hole, my project was unable to find my "*#include*"s. After dinking around in the Project Options, I set the "include" path to add the "include" folder in my OpenSSL installation, and the "lib" path to add the "lib" folder in my OpenSSL installation.

This solved my issue of not being able to find the files, but now I am getting linker issues:

**[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_EVP_EncryptInit_ex' referenced from C:\filepathhere**

I have searched online for solutions to this problem, and there are many suggested solutions for this particular problem! However, none of them are resolving my issue, and I am unsure if that is because they are incorrect solutions or perhaps I am not executing them properly. It is hard to tell since most of this is new to me.

My project's target platform is set to Win64, so I initially thought that perhaps the OpenSSL library I was linking to was for Win32. I have tried switching the target platform to Win32, as well as installing a seperate OpenSSL for 64-bit, but neither of these solutions have worked. (When switching the target platform to Win32, the error becomes **[ilink32 Error]** instead of **[ilink64 Error]**).

I then tried going through the following suggested solutions:

[linker error with openssl (trying SH1 example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543385/linker-error-with-openssl-trying-sh1-example)

[How do I solve an unresolved external when using C++ Builder packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727001/how-do-i-solve-an-unresolved-external-when-using-c-builder-packages)

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=113166

[Use OpenSSL in C++Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582334/use-openssl-in-cbuilder#)

But, none of them succeeded. To make matters worse, the listed solutions vary so greatly that it becomes increasingly difficult to know whether or not I had stumbled upon the solution at one point (and executed it improperly) and am now simply wasting my time looking for a new solution.

I'd also tried using Embarcadero's official wiki page on OpenSSL, but the installation steps did not help.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/OpenSSL

I am now at my wit's end. All I want to do is use OpenSSL with Embarcadero 10.1, using C++, on a Windows 10 machine, to develop a 64-bit application.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I apologize if this ends up being a duplicate question. Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved - received help from another user on a different forum.

One of the above links ([Use OpenSSL in C++Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582334/use-openssl-in-cbuilder#)) had an answer that involved building libraries off the .dll files from OpenSSL. The libraries are built using the implib (for 32bit) and mkexp (for 64bit) commands. See the linked thread for further details on these commands and how they work.

I had set my project options to point at these created library files (.a in my case), but have been informed that they also need to be added to the project itself. After adding them to the project, the linker errors have been resolved.

Hope this helps anyone else who may have the same issue in the future. Cheers.